# How does ios::fmtflags works in C++?How setf() works?

Tags: c++, io, formatted

I am trying to understand formatted flags of ios stream. Can anyone please explain how this `cout.setf(ios::hex | ios::showbase)` thing works? I mean how does the or (`|`) operator work between the two ios formatted flags?
Please pardon me for my bad english.

Comment: Read the source. It's complicated code and it's not modern and idiomatic by current standards though. Also, step through the code with a debugger. For reference, try getting hold of "C++ IOStreams and Locales", it explains pretty much everything concerning these parts of the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ios_base::hex` and `std::ios_base::showbase` are both enumerators of the [*BitmaskType*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BitmaskType) `std::ios_base::fmtflags`.  A *BitmaskType* is typically an enumeration type whose enumerators are distinct powers of two, kinda like this: (`1 << n` means 2<sup>*n*</sup>)

```
// simplified; can also be implemented with integral types, std::bitset, etc.
enum fmtflags : unsigned {
    dec      = 1 << 0, // 1
    oct      = 1 << 1, // 2
    hex      = 1 << 2, // 4
    // ...
    showbase = 1 << 9, // 512
    // ...
};
```

The `|` operator is the bit-or operator, which performs the or operation on the corresponding bits, so

```
hex             0000 0000 0000 0100
showbase        0000 0010 0000 0000
                -------------------
hex | showbase  0000 0010 0000 0100
```

This technique can be used to combine flags together, so every bit in the bitmask represents a separate flag (set or unset).  Then, each flag can be

- queried: `mask & flag`;
- set: `mask | flag`;
- unset: `mask & (~flag)`.